# How to select rows where object is contained in cell's list

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a MWE of my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {"A": [[1,2,3],[2,3]], "B": ["Hey", "Test"]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df.loc[1 in df["A"]]
```

throws

> KeyError: 'True: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'

I tried a function like so:

```
t = lambda x, y: y in x 
df.loc[t(df["A"],1)]
```

but the error persists. How can use `in` operator, or actually *any* operator that is not comparing two strings? I have a feeling the issue is that I am using lists in my cells and pandas doesn't like me doing it, but I don't know, I'm not super experienced with the library.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to get when issuing the command ```df.loc[1 in df["A"]]'''

Comment: I am expecting the expression to select the first row, as in its column `"A"` `1` is contained.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `apply` to mimick the expected behaviour:

```
df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: 1 in x)]
```

output:

```
           A    B
0  [1, 2, 3]  Hey
```

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense, thanks! I used `apply` before but didn't think of as an extended selection mechanism. I wonder though, why can I not use any boolean expression as shown above?

Comment: @MarcelB I had forgotten to add the slice, the `apply` only gives a boolean for slicing

Comment: `1 in df["A"]` would only check if `1` is present as an element in the index of the Series, not in the sublists.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to `explode` "A" and use `groupby_any` to see if any matches appear:

```
num = 1
msk = df['A'].explode().eq(num).groupby(level=0).any()
out = df[msk]
```

Output:

```
           A    B
0  [1, 2, 3]  Hey
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the entire first row by using `df.iloc[0]`:
which yields

```
A    [1, 2, 3]
B          Hey
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

You can select the entire first column by using `df['A']`
which yields:

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1       [2, 3]
Name: A, dtype: object
```

You can select just the first row of the 'A' column by `df['A'].iloc[0]`
which yields:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

You can then slice the first row Col A entry to get the first value by `df['A'].iloc[0][0]`
which yields:

```
1
```